# Auto-update field B in Sanity Object when field A is updated

Tags: javascript, sanity

I have the following Sanity object:

```
export const addressType = {
    name: 'address',
    title: 'Address',
    type: 'object',
    fields: [
      {
        name: 'address', 
        type: 'string', 
        title: 'Address',
        components: {
            input: GeolocationInput,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'lat', 
        type: 'number', 
        title: 'Latitude',
      },
      {
        name: 'lng', 
        type: 'number', 
        title: 'Longitude',
      },
    ]
}
```

I have created a function called getCoordinatesFromAddress that successfully makes an API call to the Google Geocode API and returns the lat and lng of the provided address.

I would like to know write a function that updates the value of the lat and lng field in my addressType object, but am struggling with Sanity's onChange() and set() functions. All of my attempts so far have resulted in the address field being updated with an object containing the lat, lng.

Any insight on how to target specific key-value pairs of an object other than the one where the value is being input?

Thanks!